# Add Google play SDK to Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play-services

I try to add google play services to my android app but in compile time fails.

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dbaile.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlign true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
}
```

I have "Google play services" V21 and "Google Repository" V13 SDK installed. The gradle sync goes great. But when i go to build my application i have this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\xxx\AndroidSDK\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output D:\Documentos\AndroidStudio\DBaile\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug D:\Documentos\AndroidStudio\DBaile\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug D:\Documentos\AndroidStudio\DBaile\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug D:\Documentos\AndroidStudio\DBaile\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\android-support-v4-f658d68db7f86c0620c54bffd0fd34f6b22d2055.jar D:\Documentos\AndroidStudio\DBaile\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-249ec408a927bbcc7d8946543bc62d471a008cb8.jar D:\Documentos\AndroidStudio\DBaile\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\classes-ead47c12a26c5912b47a682a2596f1ab902eb577.jar D:\Documentos\AndroidStudio\DBaile\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-20.0.0-7a914be15ad7ab72b458c1b59a579044ed2f61de.jar D:\Documentos\AndroidStudio\DBaile\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\support-annotations-20.0.0-97822065c059a8d0a913a12a4f49be833d40e415.jar
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

My Android studio version is 0.8.9, If I remove the line "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'" from dependencies the app compile. 
My last play-services version is 6.1.71, i see in "SDK-PATH\sdk\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services"

I followed the instructions, but i can't compile my app, https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

What can i do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat..

and

```
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

The problem is that you are including the support library twice. Remove the `compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')` line from your build script.

Comment: Thanks, finaly i remove the two lines and it works. I dont know how, but it import support v4 library.

Answer (score 0):

for this play version you need to use the latest tooling like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dbaile.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlign true
        }
    }
}
```